How do I add a glow effect to match the rest of this ceiling light in Photoshop?
there was a section of the light that was out that I was able to add some color to to closely match, but now I am trying to find a way to match the glow around it - I've tried using the outer glow but don't feel like it is accomplishing what I need it to. Can anyone point me in the right direction?


Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Can you share the original before you edited it?
